# Permanent resident in France with Job offer in Germany

Tags: visa, eu, working

I have a permanent resident permit in France ( I am an non EU national), that is it is valid for 10 years renewable. I am working full time on CDI for one employer in France since 6 years. Have been here in France almost 8 years. I have a prospective job offer based in Germany which is interesting. However, I want to know if I can work in Germany and relocate there hassle free with the residency card that I have. My fiancée and live in partner in France is a British Citizen although we don't plan to marry right away.

Will I be able to tell this potential employer that I have right to work in Germany? Do I have to go through application of whole new Germany residency card?
Also, I am interested in working in the UK as my partner would like to go back to his home country- in this case I suppose the French permanent residency doesn't help at all or does it?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Would you be traveling and living in Germany with your fiancee?